# What next if a user got the answer by my comments?

Tags: support, comments, unanswered-questions, answers-as-comments

A user has posted a question on Stack Overflow (but it could have been any Stack Exchange site) and I have added some comments. The user has got the answer through my comments. What next – the question is still open?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have answered their question, compile your comments into a full-fledged answer (and delete the comments to reduce the noise). Comments are meant to improve the question; if you accidentally happen to answer the question, no problem *at all*, but turn those [temporary notes](/help/privileges/comment) into a permanent post. Remember that we're not only here to help the author of the question, but also **future visitors** with the same problem.